# Ubuntu 18.04-19.04 HDMI screen not detected

Tags: 18.04, dell, intel-graphics, 19.04, hdmi

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 and 19.04 on my Dell Inspiron 17 3000 Series - 3793. Under Windows, the screen is well detected but not under Ubuntu... I upgraded the Ubuntu to see if the bug would be fixed without result.
Here is the result of the xrandr command

```
$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
```

In the details of the PC, I have this :
Carte graphique : llvmpipe (LLVM 8.0, 256 bits)

The secure boot is disabled for information.

Here are some of the commands I was able to execute :

```
$ cat /etc/default/grub | grep GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

$ lsmod | egrep  'i915'
i915                 1826816  0
drm_kms_helper        184320  1 i915
drm                   487424  2 drm_kms_helper,i915
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
video                  49152  3 dell_wmi,dell_laptop,i915

$ lspci -vnn | grep -A 12 '\''[030[02]\]' | grep -Ei "vga|3d|display|kernel"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:8a52] (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Kernel modules: i915

$ uname -r
5.0.0-35-generic

$ lspci -nnk | egrep -iA3 "VGA"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:8a52] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:097a]
    Kernel modules: i915
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:8a03] (rev 03)
```

Thank you in advance for your precious help !!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, I updated the Kernel to 5.3.11 and my problem with the HDMI was solved.

But I still cannot find a solution for the driver of the intel graphic card 8a52. The pc details still show: llvmpipe (LLVM 8.0, 256 bits)